# Create custom x-axis labels for hist()

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, graph, histogram

I am using the code below to create a histogram. I've tried replacing the x-axis values using the axis code, but nothing happens other than my x-axis ends up with no labels. Does anyone have any solutions?

```
 par(mfrow=c(3,1))
 for (i in c(10,20,30)) {
   a <- rnorm(50, 90, i)
   hist(a, breaks=10, main = i, xaxt="n")
   axis(1,at=seq(-2,2,by=1/3), labels =seq(-2,2,by=1/3))
   abline(v=i * seq(-2, 2, by = 1/3) + 90, col = rainbow(length(seq(-2,2,by=1/3))))
  }
```

Comment: Did you try an xlab="name" argument in the hist() function?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! @user11599 I just tried that - it does give the x-axis a title but adding that alone doesn't re-label my values along the x axis. But, maybe I'm misunderstanding what you've suggested...

Comment: Hello @sara connor, I tried to understand your histogram but the x axis will be in the range of 70 to 110 (when i=10), so why you want your axis to go from -2 to 2?

Comment: Hi @Manu - I'm making a mock up visual to describe the distribution of another variable (which is the rnorm dist in the code) and our team want the labels to represent something different. But this code seems to work for me:   axis(1,at=i * seq(-2, 2, by = 1/3)+90, labels = c('-2.0', '-1.67', '-1.33', '-1', '-0.67', '-0.33','0','0.33','0.67','1.0','1.33','1.67','2.0' ) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want a `seq`uence in the range of the breaks with length of the length of your custom sequence. You may exploit the invisible return of `hist`.

```
set.seed(42)
op <- par(mfrow=c(3, 1))
for (i in c(10, 20, 30)) {
  a <- rnorm(50, 90, i)
  h <- hist(a, breaks=10, main=i, xaxt="n")
  sq <- round(seq(-2, 2, by=1/3), 2)
  ats <- do.call(seq, c(as.list(range(h$breaks)), length.out=length(sq)))
  axis(1, at=ats, labels=sq)
  abline(v=i * sq + 90, col=rainbow(length(sq)))
}
par(op)
```

#### Gives

[image]